Contour integration for option pricing formula of Lewis (2002)
I am looking at the paper by Alan Lewis on option formula for exponential Levy processes and he derives the call option formula to be $$C(S,K,T) = -Ke^{-rT}/2\pi\int_{iv_1-\infty}^{iv_1+\infty} e^{-izk}\phi_T(-z)/(z^2-iz)dz \quad v_1\in(1,\beta), \beta>1$$
There are two simple poles. One at z=0 with residue $-Ke^{-rT}i/2\pi$ and one at z=i with residue $Se^{-qT}i/2\pi$. So far I understand. Now, he says to move the integration contour to $v_2\in(0,1) and the call option value is by the Residue Theorem

equal to the integral along $Im(z)=v_2$ minus $2\pi i$ times the residue at $z=i$.

Blockquote
so we get the alternative call option formula $$C(S,K,T)= Se^{-qT}-Ke^{-rT}/(2\pi)\int_{iv_2-\infty}^{iv_2+\infty} e^{-izk}\phi_T(-z)/(z^2-iz)dz, \quad v_2\in(0,1) $$
My question is: How do we apply the residue theorem here and what is the contour we are using? My initial thought was to use an indented semicircle around zero because we have a singularity at zero but I dont see how I can then get my option pricing formula. Thank you for any help!

I'd use a band-like contour defined as
$$\mathcal C:[-R,R]\,\cup\,[R,R+i\nu_2]\,\cup\, [R+i\nu_2,-R+i\nu_2]\,\cup\, [-R+i\nu_2,-R]$$
in the limit $R\to\infty$.
The corresponding residue theorem would be
$$\begin{aligned}\int_\mathcal C\hspace{-0.45cm}\square\ \dfrac{e^{-izk}\phi_T(-z)}{z^2-iz}\, \mathrm dz&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\left[\int_{[-R,R]}+\int_{[R,R+i\nu_2]}+\int_{[R+i\nu_2,-R+i\nu_2]}+\int_{[-R+i\nu_2,-R]}\right]\\
&=\text{Residue}(\nu_2)\end{aligned}$$
In that limit it can be proven that the integrals over $[R,R+i\nu_2]$ and $[-R+i\nu_2,-R]$ vanish. Rearranging and isolating your integral we get
$$\int_{i\nu_2-\infty}^{i\nu_2+\infty}\ \dfrac{e^{-izk}\phi_T(-z)}{z^2-iz}\, \mathrm dz=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\ \dfrac{e^{-izk}\phi_T(-z)}{z^2-iz}\, \mathrm dz-\text{Residue}(\nu_2)$$
Whats left is finding the residue. For that we'll assume $\phi_T(-z)$ is analytic on $\mathcal C$ and on $\text{Int}\,\mathcal C$. Therefore, the only singularities are two first order poles $z=0$ on the contour and $z=i$ which may or may not be on or inside the contour, depending on $\nu_2$. This way, if $f(z)$ is the integrand,
$$\text{Residue}(\nu_2)=
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{2}\text{Res}(f(z),0)\enspace \text{if }\enspace 0\neq\nu_2<1\\
&\frac{1}{2}[\text{Res}(f(z),0)+\text{Res}(f(z),i)]\enspace \text{if }\enspace \nu_2=1\\
&\frac{1}{2}\text{Res}(f(z),0)+\text{Res}(f(z),i)\enspace \text{if }\enspace \nu_2>1
\end{aligned}\right.$$
